# Blowup of complete along closed is complete?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

Assume $X$ is a complete scheme and $B$ a closed subscheme. Is the blowup $Bl_B X$ always complete?

If $B$ is smooth, this would be clear to me. But how should I think of the case when $B$ is singular?

Another question: if $X$ is projective, is the blowup $Bl_B X$ also projective?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blowup is the projective spectrum of the graded algebra
$$
\bigoplus_{n \ge 0} I_B^n,
$$
where $I_B$ is the ideal of $B$. Therefore, it is projective over $X$. Consequently, it is complete/projective, if $X$ is.

Comment: It is so clear in this way. Thank you!